# Linux Mint 16: Skype uses 100% of CPU core

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, skype

I use Linux Mint 16 Petra 64bit Cinnamon. When I install Skype (either from repo, or directly from Microsoft) it soon starts using 100% of 1 CPU Core, doubling power consumption of my system.

I tried removing the `~/.skype` folder and logging with different account.

I tried removing the skype from repositories and [install it directly from Microsoft](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/).

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot and fix this problem?

I can't reproduce this problem with older Mints, nor with Ubuntu Saucy and Raring.

The doesn't manifest itself, if I launch skype and never log in (keep skype displaying the login screen). But if the skype was logged in before and had the high CPU consumption - clicking "Sign Out" doesn't help the problem (besides even if it did, there is little point in using skype without logging in)

---

Following the advise of @slm I can include the `strace` output. It seems that Skype is busy doing `poll` syscall... I thought that polling for resource introduces processor idling, not 100% usage.

```
 strace -c skype
[ Process PID=31614 runs in 32 bit mode. ]

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                     1           total
System call usage summary for 32 bit mode:
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 96.95   45.349256         493     92056           poll
  1.26    0.588104           2    279026           clock_gettime
  0.99    0.462877           3    183996    182979 recv
  0.33    0.156517           2     79850       468 stat64
  0.30    0.138574           2     79740           gettimeofday
  0.10    0.047275          45      1040       174 futex
  0.04    0.020046        1671        12           nanosleep
  0.01    0.003025           4       792           writev
  0.00    0.002037           2       871           write
  0.00    0.001928           3       692       143 read
  0.00    0.001482           2       944       561 open
  0.00    0.000591           2       333       238 access
  0.00    0.000584           1       466           mmap2
  0.00    0.000577           1       421           madvise
  0.00    0.000485           1       431           close
  0.00    0.000462           4       120           munmap
  0.00    0.000378           3       115           mprotect
  0.00    0.000372           4        86           fstatfs64
  0.00    0.000269           1       263           fstat64
  0.00    0.000175           3        66        29 recvmsg
  0.00    0.000113           1       121           time
  0.00    0.000108           1       113         5 lstat64
  0.00    0.000082           3        29           getdents64
  0.00    0.000056           2        30           fadvise64_64
  0.00    0.000047           3        15           openat
  0.00    0.000046          15         3           shmdt
  0.00    0.000045           2        24           sendmsg
  0.00    0.000038           2        22           clone
  0.00    0.000037           1        33           socket
  0.00    0.000032           2        13           _llseek
  0.00    0.000032          11         3           shmat
  0.00    0.000032          11         3           shmget
  0.00    0.000031           1        29           brk
  0.00    0.000027           5         6           shmctl
  0.00    0.000015           2         9           send
  0.00    0.000013           0        27           fcntl64
  0.00    0.000011           2         6         2 connect
  0.00    0.000007           2         3           readlink
  0.00    0.000007           1        13           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000005           1         4           geteuid32
  0.00    0.000005           1         4           getsockname
  0.00    0.000003           0        10           uname
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           eventfd2
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           pipe2
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000002           2         1           getpeername
  0.00    0.000001           1         2           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000001           1         2           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000001           1         2           clock_getres
  0.00    0.000001           1         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           unlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           chmod
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         3 mkdir
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           umask
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           fstatfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           flock
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           getuid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getgid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getegid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getresuid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getresgid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           gettid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           sched_getaffinity
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_thread_area
  0.00    0.000000           0         4         1 bind
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           listen
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           sendto
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           shutdown
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   46.775820                721911    184603 total
```

When I attach strace to running skype with `sudo strace -p $(pgrep skype)` I get tons of the following entries:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {7553, 920730509}) = 0
recv(6, 0xf967e5a8, 4096, 0)            = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {7553, 920937548}) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recv(6, 0xf967e5a8, 4096, 0)            = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {7553, 921039735}) = 0
recv(6, 0xf967e5a8, 4096, 0)            = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {7553, 921089170}) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}], 6, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-installation of the whole system in seemingly the same way as the affected system was installed, the problem never re-appeared.

(*And who says that you don't have to format the hard drive to solve solve problems under Linux? ;-)* )

Answer (score 3):

#### strace profile

You could try debugging it further using `strace` to see what system calls `skype` is making that are causing the surge in resources. This will show you what system calls `skype` is stuck in.

#### Example

```
$ strace -c ls
afile1  afile2  afile3  afile4  afile5
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        10           open
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        27           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getdents
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           openat
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                   110         1 total
```

#### top & htop

You can also monitor `skype` using a tool such as `top` or `htop` to see what the processes is doing overall.

[image: ss of htop]

#### strace - attaching to a running process

You can also use `strace` to attach to already running processes. This allows you to attach after they've started to misbehave.

#### Example

Say we want to attach to our already running `htop` process from above.

```
$ pgrep htop
32495
```

This is `htop`'s PID - process ID. You can use these to connect `strace`.

```
$ strace -p 32495 |& head -10
Process 32495 attached
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {0, 729724}) = 0 (Timeout)
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f685faf1000
read(3, "MemTotal:        7969128 kB\nMemF"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "e:        0\nHugePages_Rsvd:     "..., 1024) = 146
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f685faf1000, 4096)            = 0
...
...
```

---

#### UPDATE #1 - debugging the poll() syscalls

The `strace` the OP provided show a high level of `poll()` system calls. You can find out what these are via `man poll`.

```
   poll, ppoll - wait for some event on a file descriptor
```

So Skype is waiting on a file descriptor, but in this case it isn't necessarily a file, it may be, but probably it's waiting on a network resource that is wrapped in a file descriptor.

#### Example

To show this a little better here's an example. Say we were downloading a 100MB file like this using `wget`.

```
$ wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test100.zip
```

We could then see what file descriptors were in use using the command `lsof -c wget`.

```
$ lsof -c wget
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
wget    11531 saml  cwd    DIR   253,2      4096 7340394 /home/saml/media/mp3s/kids_music
wget    11531 saml  rtd    DIR   253,1      4096       2 /
wget    11531 saml  txt    REG   253,1    421712  531380 /usr/bin/wget
wget    11531 saml  mem    REG   253,1    310576  544452 /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
...
...
wget    11531 saml  mem    REG   253,1     62368  528212 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
wget    11531 saml  mem    REG   253,1 106055264  803764 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
wget    11531 saml  mem    REG   253,1     26254  660143 /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
wget    11531 saml    0u   CHR   136,2       0t0       5 /dev/pts/2
wget    11531 saml    1u   CHR   136,2       0t0       5 /dev/pts/2
wget    11531 saml    2u   CHR   136,2       0t0       5 /dev/pts/2
wget    11531 saml    3w   CHR     1,3       0t0    1028 /dev/null
wget    11531 saml    4u  IPv4 1543927       0t0     TCP greeneggs.bubba.net:55907->speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com:htt
```

Notice the last line, that's a file descriptor for our connection to softlayer.com. So the network connection is also treated as a a `poll()` to via a file descriptor. You can do the same and confirm using a command such as:

```
$ lsof -c skype
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've included the `strace` to the question.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski - this probably seems like it's going no where but bare with me, please see updates, and please confirm using `lsof -c skype`.